# python sklearn decision tree classifier feature_importances_ with feature names when using continuous values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I'm using sklearn Decision Tree Classifier with some continuous features.
When I run export_graphviz I see the same features in more than one nodes and with different values. Example:
[image]

I would like to take the top important ones and want to use feature_importances_ for that.
The problem is that feature_importances_ is array without reference to the tree nodes. I have the original features but as each one can be more than one time in the tree I'm not sure how to relate importance to node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are mixing two different things here.

1. The feature_importance_ - this is an array which reflects how much each of the model's original features contributes to overall classification quality.
2. The features positions in the tree - this is a mere representation of the decision rules made in each step in the tree. A feature position(s) in the tree in terms of importance is not so trivial.

There are some potential heuristics for understanding the relation between the two. If a feature dosn't appear in the tree it has 0 importance and generally the higher the feature is in the tree the more important it is (assuming its being compared to another feature on the same branch).